# Using Flow to Generate Sum of First 100000 / 1 Million Fibonacci terms in elixir

Tags: elixir

Update: this is not about using fibonacci.
This question is about getting To understand Flow right.

For a Fibonacci series/sum generation :

```
defmodule Fib do
    def dofib(0), do: []
    def dofib(n) when is_integer(n), do: dofib(0, 1, n-1)
    def dofib(cur, _, 0), do: [cur]
    def dofib(cur, next, count), do: [cur] ++ dofib(next, cur+next, count-1)
end

# 10000 |> Fib.dofib |> List.foldl(0, &(&1 + &2))
```

This may work < `100K.

What optimizations or de cluttering is possible here?:

```
Stream.unfold([1, 0], fn([h|t]=acc)-> {h, [h + List.first(t)|acc]} end) 
|> Stream.take(100000) 
|> Flow.from_enumerable 
|> Flow.partition(stages: 100) 
|> Flow.reduce(fn -> 0 end, fn(n, acc)-> n + acc end) 
|> Flow.departition(fn -> 0 end, &(&1 + &2), &(&1)) 
|> Stream.into(File.stream!("output.txt", [:delayed_write, encoding: :utf8])) 
|> Stream.run
```

It fails at 200K.

Comment: In addition to the excellent answer below, I'd point out that you don't need (and probably shouldn't use) recursion to calculate a Fibonacci number. In fact I think calculating a Fibonacci via recursion is O(n^x) but I may be remembering incorrectly. You'd be better off to use the phi formula to calculate Fib.  Of course I'd guess you're doing this for either a class or as a learning exercise for yourself so I suppose the asymptotic performance isn't an issue for you.

Comment: I asked this as a matter of fact not for fib, thats jist a conversation starter for utilising stream and Flow effectively. Do u think, lets say we find F_n from phi formula, we could use Flow to effectively find the Sum of first N fibs faster and Flow would not kill the system? Since  in my code above its taking fib out of order and sunming it up

Comment: If you want to learn how to utilise stream and flow effectively, it would be better to state that clearly in the question. As it stands, the question is asking how to sum a fibonnaci sequence, and the flow stuff seems to be a distraction.

Comment: I agree with Adam. Even more, you’d better ask _another_ question, since this one cannot be effectively solved with `Flow`.

Comment: I think what i see is that out of order reduction on each fib_n and summing them together is just like mapreduce.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is you are overcomplicating the task, blowing up the memory. What is asked? To get a sum. Has it asked to get the list of numbers? Nope. So far, so good.

You do not need recursions, streams, flows, folding and all that fancy crap :) Plain old good `Enum.reduce/3` would do. Just keep the current sum value alongside the current fibonaccies on each iteration.

```rb
1..1_000_000
|> Enum.reduce({{0, 1}, 0}, fn _, {{prev, fib}, sum} ->
  {{fib, prev + fib}, sum + fib}
end)
|> elem(1)
|> to_string()
|> String.length()
```

So after 5 secs approx you’d know the number has `208988` digits. Remove two last lines to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start to look into concurrency, fixing some key problems with the original algorithm would be better. Especially this line:

```elixir
[cur] ++ dofib(next, cur+next, count-1)
```

This has two problems.

1. It's keeping the entire list in memory, and building it up in the call-stack.
2. It's not using tail-recursion. This will cause the call-stack to get out of control.

Here's an alternative that uses tail recursion and doesn't maintain the list on the stack:

```elixir
def sumfib(0), do: 0
def sumfib(n), do: sumfib(0, 1, 1, n)
defp sumfib(_first, _second, sum, 1), do: sum

defp sumfib(first, second, sum, dec) do
  new_second = first + second
  sumfib(second, new_second, sum + new_second, dec - 1)
end
```

This works fine for 200K. It slows down at 1M, but still returns the result in a few seconds on my machine.

Comment: Ive done something similar Adam. Thanks. Above SO was to see how Flow could ve used

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use `Stream`s, `Stream.resource/3` is your friend:

```
iex(1)> fib = Stream.resource(fn -> {1, 1} end, fn {a, b} -> {[a], {b, a + b}} end, fn _ -> nil end)
#Function<55.117072283/2 in Stream.resource/3>
iex(2)> fib |> Stream.drop(1_000_000) |> Enum.take(1) |> hd
```

To get the millionth Fibonacci number, run `fib |> Stream.drop(1_000_000) |> Enum.take(1) |> hd()`. It'll take ~5 seconds, and is 200K+ digits long, but it's doable in finite time.

Summing the first `100_000` is as easy as `fib |> Stream.take(100_000) |> Enum.sum()`.

Both results can be seen here, because they're way too big for an SO comment: https://gist.github.com/DoggettCK/7f7eb906e455179af400b739b84e8960

You could also do the mathematical equation version using phi, but Erlang's `:math.pow` dies at surprisingly low values.

```
iex(11)> fib = fn(n) ->
...(11)> phi = (1 + :math.sqrt(5))/2
...(11)> (:math.pow(phi, n) - :math.pow(-1/phi, n))/:math.sqrt(5) |> round
...(11)> end
#Function<6.128620087/1 in :erl_eval.expr/5>
iex(12)> fib.(10)
55
iex(13)> fib.(10000)
** (ArithmeticError) bad argument in arithmetic expression
    (stdlib) :math.pow(1.618033988749895, 10000)
```